# Visual Studio can not open project have lots of files

Tags: visual-studio

My solution has more than million files. 
When I try to open solution with Visual Stodio.Net 2013, it tries to load all files then crashes.
If I first hide files in windows explorer then I can open it but it takes 30 minutes to set hide or unhide.
I know there is a setting in Visual Studio but couldn't remember it.
Is there any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for curiosity, Are all these files source code files? (.cs or .vb)

Comment: How did you get 1M files in a solution if you can't even open it? Was the solution file generated by a tool, or migrated from a previous Visual Studio version?

Comment: Does the solution contain a single project with 1M files or do you have multiple projects? Visual Studio can load multiple projects in parallel, but obviously a single project has to be loaded as a whole

Comment: no they are not source code files. And I dont't want to extract these files to another location. I know that there is a solution for this on VS but can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio simply can't scale to a project of this size.  There is no hard limit on the number of files but one million is certainly too many.  Try breaking your project into several projects each containing a more reasonable number of files.

Note: having a million files in a project seems quite extreme.